# Scroll and mouse event animated header

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll, mouseevent

I'd like my header to shrink on scroll, resize if it's moused over and return to being shrunk on mouse leave (if that's a grammatically correct sentence).

My problem is that my noob code makes the header shrink on mouse leave even when the page hasn't been scrolled, and I don't want that. What's the best way to prevent that?

Thanks and please be merciful to a humble noob.

http://jsfiddle.net/ex_jedi/nam3tnxL/1/

HTML

```
<header class="header"><h1>Shrinking Header</h1></header>
```

CSS

```
.header{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 110px;
  background: #335C7D;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

.scroll {
  font-size: 8px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #efc47D;
  text-align: left;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
    $('.header').addClass("scroll");
  }
  else{
    $('.header').removeClass("scroll");
  }
});

$('.header').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.header').removeClass("scroll");
});

$('.header').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.header').addClass("scroll");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

```
$('.header').addClass("scroll");
```

with

```
     if($(window).scrollTop() > 1){
        $('.header').addClass("scroll");
     }
```

here is the modified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nam3tnxL/4/

Answer (score 2):

This is already answered well by Prakhar, but thought it worth mentioning that jQuery [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is a shortcut when using mouseenter and mouseleave on the same element. for example:

```
$('.header').hover(function() {
    $('.header').removeClass("scroll");
  }, function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 1) {
      $('.header').addClass("scroll");
    }
  }
);
```

Example added to Prakhar's fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nam3tnxL/5/

If you're using jQuery already, it might make for SLIGHTLY more manageable code :)

Comment: Interestingly/frustratingly that works fine in jsfiddle, but not on the site. Scroll resize works fine, but there's no resize on hover. Investigating...